# How to use a vector as index in eigen

Tags: c++11, eigen

In matlab, we can use a vector B to get the sublist of vector A by coding like A(B). But in Eigen, I am wondering if there is anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

With the current development branch (since mid-2018) and starting with the 3.4 releases (which will likely be released start of 2019) you can simply write `A(B)`, if `B` is either an Eigen object or a `std::vector` with integer coefficients.

See [new features](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=3.4#New_features) of the 3.4 release page for details.

Comment: Thanks! Hope 3.4 can be released soon.